# Differential equation in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the following ODE for $x$ in $\mathbb{R^n}$
$$ \textbf{x'}(t)=\frac{4\textbf{x}}{|\textbf{x}|}$$
How can I solve it given that $\textbf{x}$ is a function of time? The magnitude of $\textbf{x}$ is really confusing me. I know it should end up being some sort of exponential, right? Thank you for the help/suggestions :)

Comment: Is $x'$ = $x'(t)$?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I will fix it

Comment: I am trying to think if there is even a closed-form solution for this ODE or if it can only be done numerically given ICs and how many x's there are

Comment: I fear that this is a pretty ill-behaved ODE. On the real line, this says that $x'(t)$ is (four times) the signum function, which is a really poorly behaved ODE.

Comment: You might need to invoke some distribution-theoretic techniques to get full solutions. I'm not sure.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't seem to be an easy ODE... if it was $x''$ equals the negative of the RHS then it would just be the equation of motion of a particle around a point mass with gravitational parameter equal to 4. But it's not $x''$ :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation is only defined for $x \neq 0$.

If $x_0 \neq 0$, then the right hand side satisfies a Lipschitz condition and so a unique local solution is well defined.

It is easy to check that $x(t) = (1+4  \frac{ t }{\|x_0\|})x_0$ is a solution, hence it is the solution.

This is not surprising, the ODE says that the velocity has magnitude 4 in the direction of the current position. Hence it reduces to a one dimensional equation along the ray $\{\alpha x_0\}$.

Comment: Also worth noting:  the solution starting at $\mathbf x_0$ only exists for $t > -\Vert \mathbf x_0 \Vert / 4$, due to the presence of the singularity at $\mathbf x = 0$; also, the function $\mathbf x / \Vert \mathbf x \Vert$ is *not* Lipschitz continuous in any punctured ball centered at zero, i.e. $B(r, 0) - \{0\}$, since $\mathbf x / \Vert \mathbf x \Vert - \mathbf y / \Vert \mathbf y \Vert$ remains constant not matter how small $\Vert \mathbf x - \mathbf y \Vert$ may be.  Other than that:  Copper.hat!  Highwayman!  Our paths cross again! + 1!!! ;-)

Comment: @RobertLewis: Almost made it to Caffe Med. on Sunday, but got sidetracked...

Comment: @ copper.hat:  all roads to the Med have sidetracks!